# SQL Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

Tags: sql

This is my code and for some reason I keep getting the error that says

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

```
select course id, sec id, count(ID) as enrollment
from section natural 
join takes
where semester = 'Fall'
  and year = 2009
group by course_id, sec_id
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Natural Join with Where operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041858/using-natural-join-with-where-operation)

Answer (score 2):

It is best to avoid `natural join`.  Because it uses common field names -- and not explicitly defined foreign key relationships -- it is really just a bug waiting to happen.

You would get this problem if your database didn't support `natural join`.  The `natural` would be the table alias for `section` in this case.  This is just a guess.

I would suggest that you write the query as:

```
select course_id, sec_id, count(ID) as enrollment
from section s join
     takes t
     on s.?? = t.??
where semester = 'Fall' and year = 2009
group by course_id, sec_id;
```

You need to fill in the appropriate columns for the `on` clause.